# Deserialise and extract array data to Table from a JSON string that has a few string entries before the array entry

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, list

I have JSON string which corresponds to this C# class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string firstString {get; set;}
    public string secondString {get; set;}
    public List<Person> person{get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public string age {get; set;}
    public string fullName {get; set;}
}
```

**Line with Error:**

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(JsonString);
```

**Aim:** Aim is to get the Person details into a dataTable from a JSON string that corresponds to the class MyClass.

if deserialize had worked had planned to get the Person by Linq select and put that data into a dataTable.

while deserialising the JSON string to MyClass I get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.MyClass]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'firstString', line 1,
>   position 16."}

Comment: thanks for the edits @Caesay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is self explanatory. You are passing a single object from client and expecting it to be parsed into a collection which is wrong so either change your *JSON string* to send an array of `MyClass` or if you are passing just a single object then parse it like this:-

```
MyClass myClassObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JasonString);
```

Where your *JSON* object should look something like this:-

```
var jsonObj = {
    "firstString" : "foo",
    "secondString" : "bar",
    "person": [ { "age" : 12, "fullName" : "foo1" },
               { "age" : 10, "fullName" : "foo2" } ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks Raul.  I used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JasonString)

Comment: Thanks Raul.  I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JasonString)` as adviced but myClassObj has **NULL** values.What could be the problem?

Comment: THANKS @Rahul -**It has Worked**.

Comment: @EliudKataraihya - Nice :) You can check [Newtosoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) documentation for more.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul will go through it. Learning JSON...this is my first project using Json.